# Using a default value with an html form radio button

Tags: php

I have a web form that updates a customer record. The entries are prefilled with the data stored in mysql when called. One field shows if equipment was returned as follows:

```
<font size=5>Returned:</font><input type="text" name="ud_Returned" value="<?php echo $rtrnd; ?>" /><br />
```

My question is I setup to convert this to radio button like:

```
<font size=5>Returned:</font><input type="radio" name="ud_Returned" value=Yes /> Yes<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="ud_Returned" value="No" /> No<br />
```

But I want it so the value stored in the $rtrnd variable fills in the existing radio button with the appropriate Yes/No for that customer when form is called. Any ideas?

Comment: FYI The `<font>` tag is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this would do the trick:

```
<input type="radio" name="ud_Returned" value="Yes" <?php if($rtrnd) echo 'checked'; ?> />
<input type="radio" name="ud_Returned" value="No" <?php if(!$rtrnd) echo 'checked'; ?> />
```

Assuming that $rtrnd is a boolean value. If it isn't just use a comparison in the if statements like `if($rtrnd == 'yes')`.

Comment: No I have it set to text.

Comment: @Alan Then simply use a comparison in the if statement to match the values you would like for the yes and no inputs. Without more details on what values $rtrnd contains and what values correspond to yes and no, I cannot provide you with any more help.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your store this information as `1` or `0` in the database you'll have to -

```
<?php

// Get stuff from database
$result = /* The resulting array from your query */;

if( $result["ud_Returned"] == 1 )
{
    echo('<font size=5>Returned:</font>
          <input type="radio" name="ud_Returned" value="Yes" checked="checked" /> Yes<br />
          <input type="radio" name="ud_Returned" value="No" /> No<br />');
}
else
{
    echo('<font size=5>Returned:</font>
          <input type="radio" name="ud_Returned" value="Yes" /> Yes<br />
          <input type="radio" name="ud_Returned" value="No" checked="checked" /> No<br />');

}
```

I'm not suggesting that this is the exact implementation you should pursue but this is the logic - get information from database, make a comparison, add the `checked` attribute to the appropriate radio button.

Comment: Wanted to use the checked="checked" you suggested but unfortunately it renders properly in IE but nothing in Chrome. I'm amazed just starting out w/php & html the wide discrepancy in how the different browsers render the same code...

Comment: That's the only way of doing it with HTML as far as I know